# How can I rename a file on the SFTP with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, sftp

Is there a way to rename a file on the SFTP?

This is what I use for downloading, I am using `scp2` node module:

```
client.scp({
  'host': this.host,
  'username': this.username,
  'password': this.password,
  'path': path
  },'./', function(err) {
    if (err){
        return callback("File: "+path+" "+err);
    }else{
        return callback(null);
    }
   });
```

Maybe I could download the file, upload it with another name and remove the old one from the SFTP. But that is not neat.

I've looked through other modules such as this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sftpjs that has some rename function implemented but I can't make it work. Any suggestion? It's quite obvious use case and I couldn't find anything.

**EDIT:**
Vijay's answer is correct. I was just doing it wrong.

My code:

```
// Download swush file from SFTP
    var Client = require('sftpjs');
    var c = Client();

    c.on('ready', function () {
      c.list(function (err, list) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.dir(list);

        c.end();
      });
    }).connect({
        'host': this.host,
        'username': this.username,
        'password': this.password,
    }).rename(path.concat(oldName), path.concat(newName), function(err){
            if (err){
                console.log("Error when renaming file: "+err)
            }else{
                console.log("Renaming file successful.");
            }
    });
```

Working code:

```
// Download swush file from SFTP
    var Client = require('sftpjs');
    var c = Client();

    c.on('ready', function () {
        c.rename(path.concat(oldName), path.concat(newName), function(err) {//only one parameter err is available for rename method.
        if (err){
                console.log("Error when renaming file: "+err)
            }else{
                console.log("Renaming file successful.");
            }
        });
    }).connect({
        'host': this.host,
        'username': this.username,
        'password': this.password,
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following lines of code for renaming file:
You can use https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp for getting success in renaming file.

```
var Client = require('ftp');

var c = new Client();
c.on('ready', function() {
    c.rename('foo.txt', 'foo-new.txt', function(err) {//only one parameter err is available for rename method.
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("rename completed");
    });
});
c.connect({
 host : host,
 user : user,
 password : password
});
```

You can also use node-sftpjs module to achieve this as same way.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. Check the edit please, for the fun of it ;)

Comment: Ok thank you. Would you mind telling me why does it work without new keyword?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript. Here is the best solution for this.